# Calculate power for a non-constant force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, power

Suppose there is a body of mass $m$ in a horizontal plane, with initial velocity $v_0$, that is subjected to a force $F(t)$ (the force depends on time). How can I calculate the power developed by the force at any given time?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the power is
\begin{align}
P(t) &= \vec{F}(t) \cdot \vec{v}(t)\\
&= \vec{F}(t) \cdot \left(\vec{v}_0 + \int_0^{t} \vec{a}(t')\,dt'\right)\\
&=  \vec{F}(t)\cdot \left( \vec{v}_0 + \frac{1}{m}\int_0^{t} \vec{F}(t')\,dt'\right)\\
&= \vec{F}(t)\cdot \vec{v}_0 + \frac{1}{m}F(t){\int_0^t F(t')\,dt'}
\end{align}
I don't think you can say anything more than this without knowing $F(t)$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Power $P$ can be calculated as

$$P=Fv.$$

With time-dependent properties, you get

$$P(t)=F(t)v(t).$$

So, if you are given an expression for $F(t)$, then you just need an expression of speed to time $v(t)$ as well. Then you can just multiply them to achieve an expression of power to time.

---

One way to search for an expression for the speed would be with Newton's 2nd law,

$$\sum F_\text{total}(t)=m\,a(t)=m\frac{\mathrm d\,v(t)}{\mathrm dt}.$$

If your force $F(t)$ is the only acting force, then you can simplify this and integrate to achieve $v(t)$, still assuming that you know the expression for $F(t)$:

$$F(t)=m\frac{\mathrm d\,v(t)}{\mathrm dt}\Leftrightarrow \frac 1m\int F(t) \,\mathrm dt=v(t)+v_0$$

Here I am assuming $v_0$ as well as $m$ constant.

Comment: You forgot the arrows on the vectors. The power is:

$$ P=\overrightarrow{F}. \overrightarrow{v}  $$

Comment: @Shaktyai Sure, you can generalize this to vector notation. I kept them as scalars assuming same directions for simplicity here; same relations apply. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

**P = W/T**,
Instantaneous power is $$F.dx/dt
                    = Fv (dx/dt = v)$$
I think the the $F(t)$ will be known which can
give you the equation of v(t) by
$ v_0 + \int F/m .dt$
in $F.v$

Which is $$P =  F.(v_0+ \int a(t).dt  $$
$$a =  F/m$$
$$P = F.(v_0 + 1/m \int F.dt) $$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).